# How to click on left side menu item

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I am facing issue clicking on a left menu item (Menu Item name in page displays as "Mailbox Send"). HTML looks like below.

```
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td width="150" align="left" class="navcolor" height="22"><b><a class="WhiteNavLink" href="http://ttgllpgisapp02:5000/mailbox/jsp/MBISend.jsp?securetoken=1461807919764oodj56n5jdvg1rekn7iz154io" target="view_body">&nbsp;&nbsp;Mailbox Send&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></b></td>
</tr>
```

I tried using xpath but it didn't worked, xpath looks like :

```
/html/body/form/table/tbody/tr/td/table[3]/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/b/a
```

Please help me with some idea how to click on the element.

Comment: What on earth are you asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using `selenium`, I would actually use a "by link text" locator here.

Example in Java:

```
driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Mailbox Send")).click();
```

As for the XPath, you can still get it by text, but, first, you need to *normalize space*:

```
//a[normalize-space(.) = "Mailbox Send"]
```

Comment: Thanks, Alecxe, yes I am usng selenium with java. I tried your above examples but still getting error saying "Unable to locate element"

Comment: @Pinakee okay, let's assume this is a timing issue. Could you try using [`WebDriverWait`](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp) and wait for the element to be clickable before clicking it? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, Alecxe, Still I am getting Unable to locate element error. Tried below code. Here it's waiting for 10 seconds, by that time page loads successfully and avaialable to click.         WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[normalize-space(.) = 'Mailbox Send']")));
        element.click();

Comment: Can anyone help me here, Is there any other way to locate and click the element. I tried Xpath as well but not working.

Comment: @Pinakee can you check if this element is inside an iframe or not?

Comment: Yes alecxe, it seems it's inside a frame

Comment: Thanks alecxe, after switching to frame it worked, thanks for you all guidance.